# Is this schema of homogeneity equivalent to Reflection?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

Take the theory $\sf ZFC + classes$ exposited in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661308/is-zfc-classes-equi-interpretable-with-mk/) posting. Now replace the axiom schema of replacement in non-class style by an axiom of limitation of size, that is: $$\forall \mathcal X \subset \mathcal V \ (\mathcal X \in \mathcal V \iff |\mathcal X| < \mathcal V)$$ where $\mathcal V$ is the class of all *sets* (i.e. objects of the first sort).

Now add the following **homogeneity** axiom schema: $$ \phi^1 \iff \phi^2$$, where $\phi^1, \phi^2$ are homogeneous in non-class, class style respectively, and each is the other formula re-written in its style.

Now clearly this theory call it $\sf ZFC + classes_3$ would interpret both $\sf ZFC + classes$ and [$\sf ZFC + classes_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661308/is-zfc-classes-equi-interpretable-with-mk/). But here it is stronger since it clearly interprets [$\sf MK$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory). This theory proves the existence of a class that is of inaccessible cardinality, and thus a set likewise, but this would further pump $\mathcal V$ to the next inaccessible and so there must be a set likewise, and so on...

> Now is this homogeneity axiom acting in a way similar to reflection acting on top of limitation of size axiom, like the theory [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317658/what-is-the-strength-of-adding-limitation-of-size-and-a-simple-version-of-reflec)? or is it weaker? or is it stronger acting like the [resemblance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074980/is-reflection-consistent-with-resemblance) axiom schema presented in this theory? or is it even inconsistent?